# Using pointers or not using them for class references. What's the difference?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have functions that return an object, but I'm confused that should I return the object itself or a pointer to the object?

Here is an example of my function:

```
CImage CDocument::AddImage(string Name, string fileName)
{
    CImage img = CImage();
    img.Name = Name;
    img.Path = fileName;
    img.IwImage = Iw2DCreateImage(&fileName[0]);

    Images.push_back(&img);

    return img;
}
```

Is this correct or should I return the pointer to the object:

```
CImage * CDocument::AddImage(string Name, string fileName)
{
    CImage * img = new CImage();
    img->Name = Name;
    img->Path = fileName;
    img->IwImage = Iw2DCreateImage(&fileName[0]);

    Images.push_back(img);

    return img;
}
```

Although the last code don't compile correctly because I got this error:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'CImage' to 'CImage *'
```

I think this might be very simple question. I'm very new to c++ so bear with me.

Comment: Without seeing your code, you should probably make Name/Path/etc private and assign them in the constructor. Also, use `CImage img;` instead of `CImage img = CImage();`.

Comment: @Rubby It's not required to use new for calling constructor of CImage and create an instance of it into img? It happen automatically?

Comment: @Dane, Yes, what you're doing *should* be calling a constructor, and then calling a copy constructor to assign it. In practice, it probably wouldn't.

Comment: @chirs I added new to the first one. What should I do to prevent the img object delete automatically by garbage collector? Adding a refrence into the vector is not enought?

Comment: there is no garbage collector in C++...

Comment: @Dane, There is no garbage collector in C++. Objects on the stack go out of scope, but objects on the heap have to be cleaned up. Mario's answer explains the scope issues. We have things like smart pointers to help with cleaning up the heap allocation without having to worry about it, but otherwise you have to use `delete`.

Comment: @Dane: Even if there was a garbage collector, it would be broken if it collected objects you were using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple problems in this code, the basic difference to understand when coding in C++ is between stack allocation and heap allocation. When you do `CImage img = CImage();` the object is created *on stack*. This object is *destroyed automatically* when the function ends. Now, if you return a pointer to this object, the caller will be getting a pointer to an invalid memory location  as the object is already destroyed. You are also pushing the address of this object into the vector, which again will be invalid once the function ends. Same problem is there with the `fileName` also.

To solve this, you need to allocate memory from heap so that object is not destroyed when the function ends. You can allocate objects on heap using `new` in C++. So your code will become `CImage* pImage = new CImage();`. Note that in this case it is your responsibility to release the memory using `delete`. So you can change your function to return `CImage*` using this technique. You can also push this pointer into the vector `Images`. Note that to release the memory allocated for the `CImage` obects, you need to loop through the `Images` vector and call explicitly call `delete` on each pointer.

A better approach would be to use smart pointer such as `std::shared_ptr` in this case which will manage the calling of `delete` automatically for you.

Comment: Notice that the free vector `Images` seems to take ownership of the created object.

Comment: Thank for detailed answer. I was a Delphi programmer for a long time and I just recently moved to C++. I guess I should learn relearn everything.

Comment: Do you know what should I do with fileName. How should I solve the problem of fileName? Should I convert it to char* and how this conversion can done?

Comment: If I can assume that `Iw2DCreateImage` takes a `const char*` as the parameter in constructor and doesn't store this pointer for future use (thats how most classes would normally do), you can change the code to `Iw2DCreateImage(fileName.c_str());`.

Comment: I'm not sure about the recommendation of `shared_ptr`.  `shared_ptr` is a bit tricky; not something for inexperienced programmers.  Without knowing the semantics of `CImage`, it's actually impossible to give a recommendation.  (Until one understands pointers and dynamic allocation, it's best to use value semantics. But in this case, he's sort of stuck with the semantics Microsoft has given to `CImage`.)

Answer (score 3):

First the fix for the pointer part:

```
CImage * img = new CImage();
```

Fixes the compiler error.

Think about instance life span. An instance of a class is destroyed once it reaches the end of it's scope - here it is the closing brackets of the function.

The first example will destroy (and free the memory) for img at the end of the function - this may yieald unexpected behavior depending on the implementation of `Images.push_back` .

For the returned instance most likely a copy of the variable will be created if the calling code looks something like this:

```
CImage outterImage = myDocument.addImage(...);
```

outterImage will most likely be a copy of img, not img itself.

For more details check up on instance life cycles in C++.

Answer (score 1):

To initialize a new pointer, you need to use the `new` keyword.

```
CImage * img = new CImage();
```

This allocated a portion of memory on the heap (the nonlocal part of memory), and creates the `CImage` object there. It then grabs a pointer to that `CImage` object and returns it, giving you access to the object even after the function leaves its current scope. This is what you should do.

However, if you do `CImage img = CImage();`, you might find that you won't be able to refer to the `CImage` object after your code returns. This is because when you declare a local object (by not using `new`), it exists on the stack (the other part of memory), and gets destroyed as soon as the function returns. That means even though you have a pointer to it, the object will be gone, so trying to access it would give you a segfault.